# Should there be a gerund or a noun in front of the preposition?

Tags: nouns, gerunds

> (a) The rise of price of goods burdens the people.
>
> (b) The rising of price of goods burdens the people.
>
> (c) The ban of plastic bags is a good way to reduce environmental problems.
>
> (d) The banning of plastic bags is a good way to reduce environmental problems.

Which form should I use for the words 'rise' and 'ban' before the preposition? Gerund or noun?

Comment: A quick aside: that's not the present continuous. That's a [gerund](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gerund#Gerunds_in_English). Verbs don't take articles.

Comment: Should `environmental problem` be `environmental problems`?

Comment: And that's not the simple present either, it's *rise* as a noun.

Comment: Thanks for telling the mistake i made.I have corrected them.

Comment: @RegDwight: A completely insignificant note: the present continuous is normally a finite verb and doesn't take an article on that account; but you could say a gerund is both a noun and a verb, so that verbs can take articles... I am of that school.

Comment: @Cerberus, nice to see your thinking. While in terms of word-class, we would treat the gerund as a noun, I often think of it as the 'name' of the activity. This is how I explain it to my students, so I agree that though it is a noun, we still visualise the action.

Comment: @Karl: That, and it can take verbal arguments, i.e. it can take an object, adverb, etc.

Answer (score 1):

None of your examples really work. Try:

> The rising price of goods burdens the people.

and

> Banning plastic bags is a good way to reduce environmental problems.

Comment: I would say, "Using a computer helps us to carry out our task in a short period of time."

Comment: Thanks for your answer but i am still confused whether to use gerund or noun in the sentence.1)Use of a computer helps us to carry out our task in a short period of time.2)Using a computer helps us to carry out our task in a short period of time.Which one is correct?And is it possible to use using of computer

Answer (score 1):

I would say - **The rise of price of goods is a burden on the people.**

I prefer this because '*the rise*' is an abstract noun and giving it an active verb, while acceptable, can seem somewhat poetic.

As for the second set, I would say your sentence (d) is fine, though I would prefer: **Banning plastic bags is a good way to reduce environmental problems.**

I prefer this structure because it is a suggestion; '*The banning of*' sounds more like something that already exists/has already happened: *The banning of plastic bags made a great improvement to the situation.*

Hope this helps.